# Configure BigQuery dataset location in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, google-bigquery, azure-databricks

I need to query a table from Big Query using Azure Databricks. When I follow the official documentation (code sample below, full documentation on https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/google/bigquery.html?_ga=2.161210173.1875630365.1604488036-1915266480.1595344991#example-notebooks), I receive an error: *com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Not found: Dataset [projectId]:[datasetId] was not found in location US*.

I found out that for a dataset with location US the code below works, so it seems US is the default location. But my main dataset has a different location (EU) and so I need to be able to set the location.

```py
tableName = projectId + '.' + datasetId + '.' + tableId
tempLocation = 'databricks_testing'
query = "SELECT count(*) FROM `{table}`".format(table = tableName)

# load the result of a SQL query on BigQuery into a DataFrame
df = (spark.read.format("bigquery") 
      .option("materializationDataset", tempLocation)
      .option("query", query) 
      .load() 
      .collect()
     )

display(df)
```

Comment: Something is wrong with either the project default location, or the service account key, or the cluster that you are running.

Comment: @Pentium10 Thanks, but the same code (using the same cluster and service account key) works on a US-located dataset in the same project. Moreover, there is a package for PySpark where they mention that US is the default location and mention how to set it: `sqlContext.setBigQueryDatasetLocation("<DATASET_LOCATION>")` [link](https://github.com/samelamin/spark-bigquery/blob/master/README.md). But I was not able to apply that in Databricks.